# missing bytes while transfering files from client to server, the bytes values also represent some of the control characters

Tags: c++, file, controls, character, transfer

I'm writing a file transfer client/server application
where the client is operating on windows7 and written in vb.net
and the server is operating on linux mint and written in c++ (I'm using vmware)
my problem is when i try to upload files to the server (such as images) the received data is missing many bytes which also represent the control characters (such as EOT, ETB,...) and I guess they're read as tcp control characters and ignored by the receiving OS.
I already tested the application with simple text files (size up to 4MB) without any problem.
is there a way to prevent the system from ignoring those bytes?

this is the c++ function that receives the file:

```
string readSockBytes(int port,int num,int size)
{
  int dcmbuffSize = 1460;
  int n;
  stringstream temp;
  string strBuffer,Sbuffer;
  char Rbuffer[dcmbuffSize];
  struct socketVar sockets;
  sockets = setSocket(port);
  sockets = sockListen(sockets);
  cout<<"user connected\n";
  strBuffer = readsock(sockets);
  cout<<strBuffer.substr(0,strBuffer.find("$"))<<endl;
  if(num == atoi(strBuffer.substr(0,strBuffer.find("$")).c_str()))
    Sbuffer = "ready$";     
  else
  {
    Sbuffer = "exit$";      
    close(sockets.newsockfd);
    close(sockets.sockfd);
  }
  n = writesock(sockets, Sbuffer, 100);
  if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
  while(strBuffer.length() < fileSize)
  {
    n = read(sockets.newsockfd,Rbuffer,dcmbuffSize-1);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    temp.str(Rbuffer);
    strBuffer = strBuffer+temp.str();
  }
  strBuffer = strBuffer.substr(0,size);
  return strBuffer;
}
```

Comment: TCP in itself doesn't have any "control characters", but the protocol on top of TCP might have it. Are you using some specific protocol or are you using TCP directly with your own protocol?

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the code of the reading function and also explain which kind of class you use on VB site.

Comment: on the vb client side I'm simply reading bytes from a file then use write() and flush() to send the data.

Comment: First of all, please don't post code in comments, edit your question to include it instead. Secondly, you don't check for closed connection from the client (when `n == 0`). Thirdly, if the file contains unprintable characters (like most "control characters"), those will not show up if you try to print it. Fourthly, if the data you receive contains an embedded zero, then the string you create will be terminated by that zero, use the received length to create the string.

Comment: It would be easier to read if you edit your question and add the code. What type is strBuffer?

Comment: my problem is in the while loop. normally it should exit the loop when the file transmission is complete, but when i send an image for example the received data length is much less than the actual file size, and the server pauses waiting for the client to write on it's buffer, but the client already sent all the file bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely that you sent binary data. And binary data can contain zeros. And zeroes are the normal string terminator.

This means that when you do `temp.str(Rbuffer)` (assuming `temp` is a `std::stringstream`) then it only gets data from `Rbuffer` until the first zero.

Instead of using e.g. `std::stringstream` use `std::string`:

```
while(strBuffer.length() < fileSize)
{
    char buffer[2048];

    ssize_t n = read(sockets.newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        // An error, or connection closed
        if (n < 0)
            error("ERROR reading from socket");
        break;
    }

    // Create a string of `n` bytes, including possible string terminators
    // and add it to out current buffer
    strBuffer += std::string(buffer, n);
}
```

The important thing to remember here is that you **can't** use the received data as a string! If it's binary data it will with most certainty contain the string terminator and so you have to treat is as binary data and not a string (even though you can store it in a `std::string`).

You also need to be aware that you can't print the data, as many binary values are either unprintable or will print as "garbage".

And lastly, if you read and write binary files, you need to open them in binary modes, or you will get errors with the bytes `0x0d` and `0x0a` (i.e. carriage-return and newline).

Comment: thank you very much, now i can receive all the file data.
i used the string for testing purposes only, i want to create a file on the server till a client request it again.